# Alternative to Google Analytics for WildFly application

Tags: jboss, reporting, google-analytics, wildfly

We run a corporate web site that is hosted on a WildFly server. It is accessible through the internet, but requires individual logins for our customers. **Basically, the project is password protected and provides non-public data.**

To gain better insights to our users, we would like to install some sort of log file analyzer that tracks all users and collects technical data like browser name and version, screen resolution, language, page access counter and so on.

**Basically, something like Google Analytics, but for internal use.** I know similar projects for Apache, for example Modlogan and Webalizer. How would I enable something like this on my WildFly server? I know that it does log web access and there are a lot of monitoring tools, but I could not find any proper visualization (e.g. a world map that shows user access).

Furthermore, the mechanism must be able to deal with the password protection and must not disclose any confidential data. I know that Google Analytics can be used on intranet web sites, but, for obvious reasons, I do not want to share corporate data with a third party.

Besides implementing my own tracking software, are there any built-in modules for web access analysis in JBoss/WildFly?

Answer (score 0):

Find an alternative that you like, then configure your analysis software to use the wildfly logs and customize it to match the fields in your log files, or modify wildfly to log in the format of apache logfiles, maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58507823/6148844